# Hydrophobic interactions and Gibbs Free Energy

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to understand the basis of the hydrophobic effect.

In biochemistry, protein structures are often explained in terms of hydrophilic and hydrophobic effects.  The hydrophilic interaction is understandable in terms of electrostatic interactions but I don't understand the nature of the hydrophobic effect.

I have seen explanations in terms of the Gibbs free energy of a system. For example, if I take an oil and water mixture we know the mixture spontaneously separates, but what are the forces involved?

I get it in terms of Gibbs Free Energy:
$\Delta G = \Delta H -T \Delta S$

If the oil and water mixture is shaken so that there is an emulsion and then it's left to settle, hydrogen bonds are broken and form to the value of $\Delta H$.  I assume that more hydrogen bonds are formed as water and oil separate but I believe that the main driver is entropy.  Overall the entropy change is positive because the ordered structure of water bonds around each individual fat droplet are broken down and entropy increases, and hence $\Delta G$ is negative. OK, but to me that does not explain why individual fat particles to move.  If there's a change in inertia, then there's a force?  What is the force?

I can accept this explanation on an energetic level but what forces are acting on the oil droplets to effect this?  I can't see any Coulomb forces here.  Whilst I can accept that energetically it might make sense for oil and water to separate, I feel I need a force to explain why matter moves.  Could someone explain what the nature of the hydrophobic interaction is because I don't understand at present.
Thank you.

My explanation was taken from this link: [https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Hydrophobic_Interactions#:~:text=Hydrophobic%20interactions%20describe%20the%20relations,example%20of%20this%20particular%20interaction.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Hydrophobic_Interactions#:%7E:text=Hydrophobic%20interactions%20describe%20the%20relations,example%20of%20this%20particular%20interaction.)

Edit:  I note someone asked the exact same question.  I didn't see it before but I don't think it's been answered.

[How does the entropic force arise within the hydrophobic effect?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135081/how-does-the-entropic-force-arise-within-the-hydrophobic-effect?rq=1)

Comment: Not very clear. Which motion do you refer too? All molecules are in motion in your sample. If you mean why fat and water layer, then it is basically density. If the two phases would have very similar density but the same energetics would be involved, I suppose the emulsion would be equally unstable but it can take very long to layer.

Comment: Before Walter Kauzmann "discovered" hydrophobicity (?? see the libretext), Einstein explained theoretically [Brownian (diffusional) motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion).

Comment: Alchimista. I am asking what the hydrophobic effects is between water and non-polar substances such as hydrocarbons.  Molecules with long hydrocarbon chains are described as hydrophobic.  What is the basis for that?

Comment: The question you link to does have an answer. However your question appears to be "I feel I need a force to explain why matter moves". That's [thermal energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_energy)

Comment: I knew about that explanation.  I refer to it in my question.  I can see how the hydration entropy would lead to a lower energy state for for aggregating non-polar molecules in water but as Buck says I struggle to see how a thermodynamics sum can propel a hydrocarbon molecule to move away from water molecules.  I am probably not grasping something but it does not make sense to me.

Comment: So it is energetically favourable for hydrophobic molecules to interact with each other because by doing so the entropy of water molecules increases when they are no longer highly ordered when surrounding small particles of hydrophobic molecules. 
 OK.  I concede.  In effect I can see that an input of energy would be required to cover the loss of entropy when water bonds to itself around hydrophobic molecules, and in practical terms I can see that work would have to be done.  I don't think a hydrophobic interaction is really a very good description of this phenomena.

Comment: You appear to mix a few different topics so I'll try addressing only two. First, *equilibrium* thermodynamics deals with macroscopic bodies or with ensembles, which is to say, it describes average static (time-independent) behavior, it does not deal with forces or instantaneous values of the potentials that are typically used in describing dynamics. Non-equilibrium thermodynamics does deal with systems that are dynamic (away from equilibrium), and maybe that is a more useful tool to describe what you are interested in.

Comment: You may be right, perhaps hydrophobicity is in fact not a good term to describe what is happening when water and oil mix, because it is repulsion of oil by water that accounts for most of the work in separating the two components. Perhaps it should be called "oleophobicity". The relevant forces would be hydrogen bonding interactions between the water molecules.

Comment: Thanks Buck.  If I take two molecules, a water molecule and a lycine molecule, and I reduce their separation from infinity, I believe they would describe the Lennard Jones potential.  Initially attractive forces would be generated by induced dipoles and a net repulsion would only be exhibited when electron clouds start to interact.  I think the hydrophobic effect is a macroscopic effect due to the affinity of water to hydrogen bond with other water molecules rather than by any interaction between polar and non-polar molecules.

Comment: The hydrophobic effect does not require a macroscopic system to be evident, and it is ultimately explained in terms of entropy (the answer to the linked post explains how this works). You might think of its like this: waters like to H-bond to each other. When an apolar compound is solubilized, waters tend to form shells around the solute while continuing to H-bond with other waters. Waters about the solute have less H-bonding choices and therefore lower entropy, which is unfavorable.