# Strength of the hydrophobic interaction

Tags: bond, energy, intermolecular-forces

**How strong is the "hydrophobic force"?**

Hydrophobic interactions are weak interactions but can have greater strength than hydrogen bonds. I find the strength of the hydrogen bond in literature to be near 1 pN. Finding the strength of the "hydrophobic bond" has proven to be a bit more elusive. I would guess that there is a hydrophobic interaction strength spectrum (dipole strengths and such), but would also guess there is a fundamental order of magnitude of strength of the hydrophobic interaction.

Hydrophobic interactions result from the hydrophobic effect and manifest in measurable attractive forces. For example, the Polyhydroxyethylmethacrylate (pHEMA) backbone has dipole induced interactions, hydrophobic interactions, and hydrogen bonding; each of these interactions being identifiable in molecular position on the backbone (aliphatic regions being identified as hydrophobic sites).

To date, i have found a measurement of such resulting attractive forces in a specific interaction to be near 15 pN (oil-oil droplet AFM approach)[1]. However, I can also find literature that discusses forces in avidin-biotin  complex which are dominated by hydrophobic interactions; resulting attractive forces range from 80 to 250  pN [2].

[1] Tabor et al, 2013; DOI: 10.1021/jz402068k
[2] Moy et al, 1994; DOI: 10.1126/science.7939660

Comment: With this not being an actual force you can have some trouble here...

Comment: "The hydrophobic force describes the attraction between water-hating molecules (and surfaces) that draws them together, causing aggregation, phase separation, protein folding and many other inherent physical phenomena"
it is not a fundamental force of nature, but it is a widely recognized intermolecular force.

Comment: You may have success if you look into surface tension and consider the area of the hydrophobic interfaces you are interested in.

Comment: Get better resources https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37287/basis-for-the-hydrophobic-effect https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135081/how-does-the-entropic-force-arise-within-the-hydrophobic-effect

Comment: I refer my information from a text book titled Intermolecular and Surface Forces; Israelachvili 3rd edition. I think your comments have been a bit patronizing, and if you refer to the question i say hydrophobic interactions and use quotations around "hydrophobic force". i realize this is not perfect, but it is a phenomena despite the etropic underpinnings.

Comment: Well, I think there's a need for clarification - so-called hydrophobic effect in more of a phenomenon then force. There are obviously various interactions between induced dipoles, quadrupoles etc. but do you ask about them, then?

Comment: hydrophobic interactions result from the hydrophobic effect and manifest in measurable attractive forces. the attractive force (per interaction) apparently depends on a lot of things, which is the basis of my question. induced dipoles are not required in hydrophobic interactions but can be another sort of interaction in a molecule. for example, the Polyhydroxyethylmethacrylate (pHEMA) backbone has dipole induced interactions, hydrophobic interactions, and hydrogen bonding; each of these interactions being identifiable in molecular position on the backbone (hydroxyl groups being hydrophobic).

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect my above comment, as it might clear up what i mean and it provides an example

Comment: The type of "force" in question does not have the classical meaning as "derivative (or gradient) of energy wrt position". This is what makes providing an answer far from trivial. Say you establish that the free energy of two states of your polymer in solution differ by some amount. What do you use as "distance" to compute a force?

Comment: An ideal answer would identify the questions shortcomings, discuss these shortcomings, but also recognize and identify ranges of forces in measurable hydrophobic interactions. I think the comments so far have been extremely useful and valid, but being bogged down by these characteristics to the point where an answer is unachievable I don't think is productive.

Comment: I have edited the question to loosen language on the origin of the forces cited in the final paragraph as comments have pointed out important notes on resulting attraction forces in hydrophobic interactions.

Comment: You are right that this is a force; it is not a "conservative" force, see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force#Nonconservative_forces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hydrophobic force does not exist. It is a phenomena resulting from the following considerations.

In principle, liquids should be like gases, perfectly miscible in all proportions. This is the case for non polar molecules, like hydrocarbons. This is not the case for liquids where molecules are hold together by hydrogen bonds, like water. In these liquids, adding solutes requires to break hydrogen bonds. It is acceptable if the solute is able to form new hydrogen bonds, like with small alcohols, polyols and sugars. But if mixing with another substance will break too many H-bonds, Nature refuses to make up this mixture, as if there was a hydrophobic force. Of course, this force does not exist. It is simply a consequence that mixing very different substances would cost too much energy for breaking all H-bonds of one liquid, without forming back new ones.

Comment: I might ask: is there such a thing as a "frictional" force? Or an "elastic" force (eg in a rubber band)?

Comment: The elastic force is a result of literally stretching bonds in a solid, friction is super complicated.. probably similarly complicated to forces in hydrophobic interactions